# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener while running the project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Getting below errors while running the project

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:545)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4613)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have used spring4.3.3 and spring-security-3.2.6 for my project.
This is not a maven project.

Tried all the solutions but still facing same issue.

Comment: Please post your **entire** class containing the main method

Comment: Obviously you are missing a runtime dependent library. "Tried all the solutions..." LOL! Which solutions? You must give more details about your project. If it is NOT a maven project, what is it then? How do you configure the library dependencies?

Comment: Add all the dependencies related to Spring that you import. It seems that you need spring-web dependency but to be sure add more information

Comment: @AndresSacco spring-web i had in the project lib.

Comment: Upload your pom file or the list of dependencies in the case that you don't use Maven